# Dict Object Search

Tags: python, json, algorithm, search, data-structures

I've fetched over 8000 records from a REST API. Now I need to searching through this dataset.

My dataset is like:

```
  data = {
        key: [ 
              {name:'foo1', 'age':22},
              {name:'foo2', 'age':23},
        ]}
```

I need a new searching techniques or algorithm on python without O(n) complexity on this when I'm using this code ;

```
for data in datas:
  if data["name"] == "foo1":
     calculate_func(data)
```

How I can optimize the searching algorithm complexity?

Comment: Are you asking for a faster algorithm than O(n)?

Comment: In general, it is impossible to search better than O(n) over an arbitrary dataset. You can speed up multiple searches with an index, but building the index itself will incur an initial cost of at least O(n). To search better than O(n), you need prior knowledge of the structure of the data (e.g. the data is ordered).

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset is exactly like you posted, then you can make a dictionary of `{key:value}`, where `key` will be names and `value` will be ages. Like this -

```
dict = {
'foo1': 22, 
'foo2': 23
}
```

Then if you can use the search term directly to access value corresponding to that name. like -

```
age = dict[searchTermName]
```

In this way you will only need O(n) time to prepare the dataset, but for each search you will need O(1) time.

Now, if your dataset is more complex than that - you can use [prefix trie](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/). This will be one of the most efficient ways. In each search the worst case time complexity will be O(search_term_length). Though it has a initialization cost as well. But that's only one time cost(`O(n * key_length)`).